# Magento 2 -custom field Product Price in admin

Tags: magento2, sku, system.xml, custom-field, product-prices

how can create new field **sku,price,sale price** and a button **update price** dynamically, admin have option set and update price  dynamically.
i have tried below code etc/adminhtml/system.xml.? help me how can make it dynamically

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="irshad_custom" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>Custom Tab</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="test_section" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Price Configuration</label>
            <tab>irshad_custom</tab>
            <resource>Irshad_Ahmad::config_ahmad</resource>
            <group id="custom_settings" translate="label" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Manage Configuration</label>
                <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="product_sku" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Product SKU</label>
                    <comment>Manage multiple squ with comma separated</comment>
                    <field id="enable">1</field>
                </field>
                <field id="price" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Price</label>
                    <validate>required-entry</validate>
                    <comment>Please store price</comment>
                    <field id="enable">1</field>
                </field>
                <field id="sell_price" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Sell Price</label>
                    <validate>required-entry</validate>
                    <comment>Please store Sell price</comment>
                    <field id="enable">1</field>
                </field>
                <field id="update_price" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="40" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Update Price</label>
                    <validate>required-entry</validate>
                </field>
                <field id="update_button" translate="label" type="button" sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Update</label>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

[image]